# How do I properly convert a "for" loop to an apply loop in this case in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am having a problem trying converting this into an apply loop. When I do attempt, it, I keep getting the same output back for each row.?

This is where the data is coming from:

```
Classdata0 <- read.table('Class_Data.txt',header=T)
group <- as.character(unlist(Classdata0[1,]))
ClassMatrix <- as.matrix(Classdata0[-1,])
mode(ClassMatrix) <- 'numeric'
```

This is the for loop I am trying to convert:

```
p <- nrow(ClassMatrix)
pvalues <- numeric(p)
names(pvalues) <- rownames(ClassMatrix)

for(b in 1:p){
  test1 <- t.test(ClassMatrix[b,group == 'Alpha'], ClassMatrix[b,group == 'Sigma'])
  pvalues[b] <- test1$p.value
}
```

My latest attempt is the following:

```
a<- apply(ClassMatrix,1, FUN = function(x) {t.test(
  ClassMatrix[b, group == 'Alpha'], ClassMatrix[b, group == 'Sigma']) 
}
)
a
```

What could I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Without data its not easy to state what you are trying to do. Also it seems your data is incorrectly arranged, whereby the observations are the columns and the ariables are the rows. You need to transpose it

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I suspect this is a lazy evaluation problem.  When you `print(pvalues)`, `b` is equal to `nrow(ClassMatrix)`, so each element of `pvalues` is evaluated as `pvalues[nrow(ClassMatrix)]`.  The `apply` family of functions *force* evaluation, so the simplest solution will be to convert your `for` loop to an `lapply` or similar.  @Onyambu's observation is also relevant.

Comment: Your function in the `apply` has `x` as its argument, but `x` is never used.

Comment: As @Axeman says.. simply replace `b` with `x` in your attempt and the two things will be essentially equivalent.

Comment: I apologize that I am unable to be more clear about what I am trying todo. I was still unable to get the code to work but I found a culprit to getting closer to what I want. in the part where I have: "ClassMatrix[b, group == 'Alpha'], ClassMatrix[b, group == 'Sigma']", if i change where the "b" is located, i get the values i am looking for. As in if b is "1", I get one answer; if its 2, i get another answer and so on. But the problem is that even if i set b<- c(1:5) or even just b<-c(1), i get a "arguments must have same length" error. I replaced the "x" with "b" and still no difference.